# define myDict = {}, then myDict[['a', 'b']] = 'foo'

Tags: python, expression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A list as a key for a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698307/a-list-as-a-key-for-a-dictionary)

Is `myDict = {}`, then `myDict[['a', 'b']] = 'foo'` a legal Python expression?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? If you explain what you're expecting, and what you're getting...

Comment: You could start with the Python tutorial.

Comment: Well, it's *syntactically* valid (although it bombs at runtime).

Comment: You may use a tuple as a key to a dict. This appears to be what you're trying to do.

Comment: This question is part of the Mid Term exam on MIT 6.00x: https://www.edx.org/courses/MITx/6.00x/2012_Fall/about

Answer (score 3):

It is not. When in doubt, try it! Running this code produces:

```
dn52213m:~ austin$ python t.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 2, in <module>
  myDict[['a', 'b']] = "foo"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Your code creates a dictionary, and then tries to store an element in the dictionary with a list as a key. Unfortunately, a list is not a valid key in a dictionary :-)

Answer (score 2):

No because lists are not hashable, therefore cannot be dictionaries keys.

You can use

```
myDict['a', 'b'] = 'foo'
```

because you'll be using a tuple

Answer (score 2):

No it's isn't, as you're trying to use a list as a key, which is going to raise an error.
Dictionaries only allows immutable objects as keys, so you should use a tuple here.

```
In [9]: myDict = {}

In [10]: myDict[['a', 'b']] = 'foo'   #error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/monty/Desktop/<ipython console> in <module>()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

#using a tuple, works fine

In [11]: myDict[('a', 'b')] = 'foo'

In [12]: myDict
Out[12]: {('a', 'b'): 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not legal, because lists can't be dictionary keys (since they are mutable).  But tuples (which are immutable) can:

```
>>> myDict={}
>>> myDict[['a','b']] = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This might be closer to what you want:

```
>>> myDict['a','b'] = 'foo'
>>> myDict[('a','b')] = 'foo'  #same thing, slightly more explicit
>>> myDict
{('a', 'b'): 'foo'}
```